# How to random the order of a list in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a list of non-repetitive numbers; i need to display all these numbers in a random manner. From http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_rand.asp I learn a few approaches without luck. If i use "array_rand" all the outputs must be in an increasing order; so my final output will always be in sequential order from 1 to 10 with no randomness.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$random_keys=array_rand($a,10);
echo $a[$random_keys[0]]."<br>";
echo $a[$random_keys[1]]."<br>";
echo $a[$random_keys[2]]."<br>";
echo $a[$random_keys[3]]."<br>";
echo $a[$random_keys[4]]."<br>";
echo $a[$random_keys[5]]."<br>";
echo $a[$random_keys[6]]."<br>";
echo $a[$random_keys[7]]."<br>";
echo $a[$random_keys[8]]."<br>";
echo $a[$random_keys[9]]."<br>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if I use `array_rand` all the outputs must be in an increasing order"? Can you clarify?

Comment: 1st tip - don't use w3schools use more reputable sources like the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php). 2nd tip - use a `foreach` loop to print out your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [php array shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

print_r($a);

shuffle($a);

echo "<br/>";

print_r($a);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

The [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function will randomize the order of the elements in the array for you.

```
$a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
shuffle($a);
echo implode('<br>', $a);
```

Answer (score 2):

The PHP you're actually looking for is:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
shuffle($a);
foreach($a as $n){
  echo "$n<br>";
}
```

## [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

> Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries.

## [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

> shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array

Answer (score 1):

Use the function *shuffle* to randomize the elements of the array:

```
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
shuffle($a);
```

**Info**: http://php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$numbers = range(1, 10);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number<br>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```