# Using an array in PHP to echo numbers in a random order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, random

I have written a very simple couple of .php pages where a user chooses a times table to be tested on, and then answers questions.

At the moment they are just asked 12 random questions for that table, so could be asked the same question several times, and not be asked other questions. I am just using random number generation between 1 and 12 to achieve this.

I believe that I can enter the values 1-12 into an array, and call on them in a random order.

Does this sound like the correct way forward? If so, would someone be able to push me in the right direction? I am looking to learn from this as much as I am looking for a solution.

I have used arrays before from mysqli queries, but wouldn't say that I am 100% confident with them.

The $rand variable is used to determine which way round the question will be asked.

```
$question = 1;
$random = 0;
while ($question < 13)
{
      $random = rand(0,1);
      if ($random == 0)
      {
         $_SESSION['multiplier'.$question] = $_SESSION['table'];
         $_SESSION['multiplicand'.$question] = rand(1,12);
      }
      else
      {
         $_SESSION['multiplier'.$question] = rand(1,12);
         $_SESSION['multiplicand'.$question] = $_SESSION['table'];
      }
      $answer[$question] = $_SESSION['multiplier'.$question] * $_SESSION['multiplicand'.$question]; 
      $question++;
}
```

Comment: What about [`array_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-rand.php) or [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.shuffle.php)? Have you done any research before asking? Have you tried anything? What did you find out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to random the order of a list in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650623/how-to-random-the-order-of-a-list-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Can this help?

```
<?php
   $questions = array("Question 1?", "Question 2?",  ... );
   $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
   $newN = 0;
   shuffle($arr);

   foreach($arr as $n) {
      $newN = $n - 1;

      echo $questions[$newN];
   }
?>
```

I am not going through all the more complicated stuff, but this is basic code to do what you said.

In `$questions`, you should put the list of questions.

You probably don't want to `echo` the question but probably call on a function, which you can do.

Since I am not an expert myself, there may be an error here or I may not be understanding your question properly. In either case, please notify me.